# in this program a file is read and it contains a lot of students .in each one line there's the surname

Tags: c++, arrays, function, file, dynamic-memory-allocation

in this program a file is read and it contains a lot of students. In each line there's the surname, the name,the mark and the age of the student to which the data belong.
The problem is in the fisrt function that it doesn't read the number of students correctly 
in the function allocaVettore it makes a dynamic-allocation of an array that contains the data of the file
in the function inserimento the array is filled
in the function ordianmento there's a sort of the array
in the function carica the array sorted is written in a file of output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

#define STR_MAX 25+1
#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

struct candidato{
    int punteggio;
    int eta;
    char cognome[STR_MAX];
    char nome[STR_MAX];
};

int leggiFile(const char * nomeFile);
candidato * allocaVettore(int numElem);
void inserimento(candidato vett[],int numElem,const char * nomeFile);
void ordinamento(candidato vett[],int numElem);
void caricaFile(const candidato vett[],int numElem,int numAmmessi);

int main(){
candidato * vett;
char nomeFile[STR_MAX];
int numElem;
int numAmmessi;
    cout<<"Dimmi il nome del file da aprire"<<endl;
    cin.getline(nomeFile,STR_MAX);
    cin.clear();
    numElem=leggiFile(nomeFile);
    cout<<numElem;
    if(numElem>0){
        vett=allocaVettore(numElem);
        if(vett!=NULL){
            inserimento(vett,numElem,nomeFile);
            ordinamento(vett,numElem);
            do{
                cout<<"Dimmi il numero di persone ammesse"<<endl;
                cin>>numAmmessi;
                while(cin.get()!='\n');
            }while(numAmmessi<=0 || numAmmessi>numElem);
            caricaFile(vett,numElem,numAmmessi);
            cout<<"E' stato creato un file chiamato lista_graduatoria.txt contente i risultati"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            exit(-1);
        }

    }
    else{
        exit(-1);
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int leggiFile(const char * nomeFile){
ifstream file;
int temp1;
char temp2[STR_MAX];
    file.open(nomeFile);
int numElem=0;

    file>>temp2;

    while(file!=NULL){
        file>>temp2>>temp1>>temp1;
        numElem++;
        file>>temp1;
    }
    file.close();
    return numElem;
}

candidato * allocaVettore(int numElem){
candidato * vett;
    vett=new candidato [numElem];
    if(vett!=NULL){
        return vett;
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

void inserimento(candidato vett[],int numElem,const char * nomeFile){
ifstream file;
int i=0;
    file.open(nomeFile);
char c;
    file>>vett[i].cognome;

    while(file!=NULL){
        file>>vett[i].nome>>vett[i].punteggio>>vett[i].eta;
        i++;
        file>>vett[i].cognome;
    }

}

void ordinamento(candidato vett[],int numElem){
int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<numElem-1;i++){
        for(j=i;j<numElem;j++){
            if(vett[i].punteggio<vett[j].punteggio){
                candidato temp;
                    temp=vett[i];
                    vett[i]=vett[j];
                    vett[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<numElem-1;i++){
        for(j=i;j<numElem;j++){
            if(vett[i].punteggio==vett[j].punteggio){
                if(vett[i].eta<vett[j].eta){
                    candidato temp;
                    temp=vett[i];
                    vett[i]=vett[j];
                    vett[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void caricaFile(const candidato vett[],int numElem,int numAmmessi){
int i;
    ofstream outfile;

    outfile.open("lista_graduatoria.txt");
        outfile<<"\t LISTA AMMESSI PER IL CORSO"<<endl<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<numElem;i++){
        if(i<numAmmessi){
            outfile<<vett[i].cognome<<" "<<vett[i].nome<<"\t "<<"punteggio:"<<vett[i].punteggio<<" \t "<<"eta:"<<vett[i].eta<<"\tAMMESSO"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            outfile<<vett[i].cognome<<" "<<vett[i].nome<<"\t "<<"punteggio:"<<vett[i].punteggio<<" \t "<<"eta:"<<vett[i].eta<<"\tNON AMMESSO"<<endl;
        }
    }
    outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. Lastly please tell us what's wrong with the program you show, and don't forget to actually *ask a question*.

Comment: Unrelated but `if(vett!=NULL){return vett;} else{ return NULL;}` is exactly the same as `return vett;` And `file!=NULL` should not even compile.

Comment: @churill Regarding `file!=NULL` it works because [the `operator void*` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: @churill ok and with what i have to change file!=NULL?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that is a good cite, I did not know that, but I must admit looking at it written that way in the code just strikes me as awkward -- though it is fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ahh, you're right, but only up to c++11. I tried it only with C++17.